# shell command fails with subprocess.call() in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm failing to run a shell command from a python script using subprocess.call().  The test below works if I copy the python output and paste into the shell but not when I call the command via subprocess.call().  Can Anyone throw some light on my error/thinking please?  I am just starting with Programming and think this is a "can't see the wood for the trees" thing, there are other posts about this but I can not apply them to my problem.

I think the shell script is not getting its arguments.  I have set `shell=True` and tried ' and " around args with whitespaces.

```
import subprocess as s

fromCall = 'MB7UZ-1'
toCall = 'APRS'
path = 'via WIDE1-1'
ax25Port = 'aprs'
command = "/sbin/beacon"
packet = ":Test Beacon 4"

command_args = "-c '{0}' -d '{1} {2}' -s {3} '{4}'".format(fromCall, toCall, path, ax25Port, packet)

s.call([command, command_args], shell=True)
print repr(command_args)
```

prints the following to the console

```
/sbin/beacon -c MB7UZ-1 -d 'APRS via WIDE1-1' -s aprs ':Test Beacon 4'
```

If I copy that whole line and paste back into the shell the /sbin/beacon program works as expected.

I have searched extensively here and Google, some posts suggest converting the arguments to UTF-8 ...

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2013, 13:38:49)
[GCC 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale ; locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

... I don't think this is the problem given the output above but somehow still find myself mentioning it!

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `s.call` should look like this: `[command, "arg1", "arg2", "arg3", ...]`, you're passing `[command, "arg1 arg2 arg3"]` so `/sbin/beacon` is only getting one argument which is:

```
-c MB7UZ-1 -d 'APRS via WIDE1-1' -s aprs ':Test Beacon 4'
```

You have two options, the better one is to split up the arguments. Something like:

```
import subprocess as s

fromCall = 'MB7UZ-1'
toCall = 'APRS'
path = 'via WIDE1-1'
ax25Port = 'aprs'
command = "/sbin/beacon"
packet = ":Test Beacon 4"

command = ["/sbin/beacon", "-c", fromCall, "-d", " ".join((toCall, path)), "-s",
           ax25Port, packet]
s.call(command)
```

Or the option I like less, pass a single string to `s.call` and let the shell split the arguments for you. You can only do this if you use `shell=True`.

```
import subprocess as s

fromCall = 'MB7UZ-1'
toCall = 'APRS'
path = 'via WIDE1-1'
ax25Port = 'aprs'
command = "/sbin/beacon"
packet = ":Test Beacon 4"

command = command + " -c '{0}' -d '{1} {2}' -s {3} '{4}'".format(fromCall, toCall, path, ax25Port, packet)

s.call(command, shell=True)
print repr(command)
```

Comment: actually it is even worse. It is the shell that is getting the argument (`shell=True` is equivalent to `['/bin/sh', '-c'] + [command, "arg1 arg2 arg3"]` here). Use `pipes.quote` in your 2nd code example.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I'm not too familiar with `pipes.quote`. Feel free to edit my answer if you want to add it.

Comment: I would just remove `shell=True` variant.

Comment: Thank you Bi Rico, I guess I misread the manual and did not realise you add arguments as a list.  

J.f.Sebastian, thanks for the comment - the manual says `pipes.quote` is depreciated as of 2.7 and to use `shlex` instead.  You comment has given me another thread to follow up, thanks!

Comment: @BiRico I used your first example and it works great.  Now I understand arguments I will try and implement with `Popen`.  This now makes sense , Thanks!! ;-)

Comment: @user2989937: the docs are wrong (an opportunity for you to [provide a doc patch](http://docs.python.org/devguide/docquality.html)). `shlex.quote()` is not available until Python 3.3 and even when `pipes.quote is shlex.quote`. You can use `pipes.quote()` in Python 2.7.